# Why does @typescript-eslint cache old types/files and fail to compile?

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I start my Typescript application with `tsc -b -w` and am consistently finding that `@typescript-eslint` does not respond to file changes correctly. It will report invalid types/syntax where no problems exist. Sometimes, even restarting the process does not fix the problem. The only way to fix it is to make whitespace edits to the file and save again, hoping that this time things work.

**Example**

I just created an interface in `./types.ts`:

```
export interface IHaveWorkspace {
  workspace: Workspace;
}
```

I then import and attempt to use this interface in `index.tsx`. However, when I attempt to access `myObj.workspace`, I get the following errors:

```
[1] src/components/Navigation/index.tsx
[1]   Line 26:29:  Unsafe assignment of an any value                @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
[1]   Line 26:29:  Unsafe member access .workspace on an any value  @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access
```

Notably, it is not complaining about the interface itself. It seems unable to understand the interface's types, but it does not raise any other errors (e.g., importing the interface). Saving the files and even restarting the process have no effect. Eventually, after making whitespace changes and saving some more, the errors magically go away.

**Config**

FWIW...

`.eslintrc.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', 'eslint-plugin-react', 'eslint-plugin-react-hooks'],
  extends: [
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking',
    'prettier',
    'prettier/@typescript-eslint',
  ],
  rules: {
    'indent': ['error', 2],
    'linebreak-style': ['error', 'unix'],
    'quotes': ['error', 'single'],
    'semi': ['error', 'always'],
  },
  env: {
    amd: true,
  },
  parserOptions: {
    project: './tsconfig.json',
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
  },
};
```

And `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "esnext",
    "allowJs": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "rootDir": "src",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: If you can setup a reliable, isolated reproduction - you should file an issue at the project. https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint

Comment: Of course. But if I had the days required to isolate the issue, I wouldn't be asking here. The problem is, by its very nature, spurious and hard to pin down,

Comment: (Speaking as the maintainer of the project) `any`s can be reported for a number of reasons - usually related to TS being unable to resolve the type. In the case of imported types, this usually is due to a misconfiguration somewhere. TS-ESLint does zero caching between runs, and it does not leverage TS's incremental build cache. Which further points towards a configuration issue. But without a decent repro it's going to be hard/impossible to give much guidance.

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful context! It *seemed* like a caching issue, so I would have been going down the wrong rabbit-hole without this comment. I'll work on a repro, though it may take some time to isolate. FWIW, this happens *much* more frequently when I use "save all" or a code-generation tool. If I'm careful to save the files one-by-one, it seems much less common. The most common time it happens is using graphql-codegen to regenerate my `graphql.ts` file. If I change a type of an existing object, it almost always causes this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If this is happening in VS Code *(based on the comments, it seems like it is?)* then it's a known issue with how VS Code's ESLint extension handles re-running lint rules on file changes: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/1774. Specifically, the extension doesn't re-compute cross-file information -such as types- when files change. The fastest way to get it to refresh its understanding is to run the *Restart ESLint Server* editor command in VS Code.

If this is happening on the command-line *(for other folks seeing this)*, make sure you're not using ESLint's `--cache`. ESLint's caching also doesn't recognized cross-file dependencies: https://typescript-eslint.io/troubleshooting/#can-i-use-eslints---cache-with-typescript-eslint